# Can I set SSH known_hosts to ignore a specific hostname?

Tags: ssh, known-hosts

I've set up a few headless Raspberry Pi systems using a Raspbian system image lately. They default to using the zeroconf domain name `raspberrypi.local`. Before I can change it, I have to connect to the new server with SSH, which always barks at me:

```
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> @      WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!           @
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

and won't connect until I open the known_hosts file and delete the previous entry. Then when it does connect, it automatically adds a new entry for `raspberrypi.local` to mess things up next time.

I understand and appreciate the logic of checking the keys and automatically adding new ones, but I think for this specific case it doesn't make sense. I would never be connecting to a server called `raspberrypi.local` unless it was a new server I just plugged in, and in that case it will *never* have a known trustworthy key.

I can see from the [known_hosts specification](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd#SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_FORMAT) that I can set a wildcard on the *address* side (ie. accept this key from any address in this range) but what I want to do is set a wildcard on the key side (accept any key from this particular domain name). Or better yet, just don't check keys from this domain name at all.

Is there any way to tell known_hosts to ignore (pass without checking keys from) a single specific domain name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your `ssh_config`, this prevents ssh from saving the key, but only for this hostname.

```
Host raspberrypi.local
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

The manual also mentions `StrictHostKeyChecking`:

> If this flag is set to “no” or “off”, ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files and allow connections to hosts with changed hostkeys to proceed, subject to some restrictions.

But I found no details on those restriction, and you don't want to save the hostkey anyway.

Comment: This is great. It still gives a warning and makes me type "yes" to continue, and it still says it added the key to the list of known hosts, but the actual known_hosts file doesn't change. I turned off StrictHostKeyChecking and it no longer gives a warning or makes me type "yes", but it still erroneously says added to the list of known hosts. Close enough though.

Comment: Well, it does write the key to `/dev/null`.